# Angular Js: date field from database showing one day less

Tags: angularjs, sql-server, json, date

What I have in my @Entity Person class -

```
@JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")
private Date dob;
```

What I am printing on screen-

```
 <tr ng-repeat="person in vm.persons">
       <td>{{person.id}}</td>
       <td>{{person.name}}</td>
       <td>{{person.location}}</td>
       <td>{{person.dob}}</td>
  </tr>
```

the person.dob is showing date 1 day lesser than what exist in the database.
What could be the possible reason ?
Note:

> I have dob as date type in database which is Microsoft SQL Server.
>   The JSON response from REST call returns timestamp which is being converted to yyyy-mm-dd format as shown above.

Example of issue:- 
In database dob(s) are:-

```
dob
1989-05-18
1989-05-18
1970-01-01
```

on screen showing as below-

```
Person Dob
1989-05-17
1989-05-17
1969-12-31
```

> Let me know if need more info on the issue.

Comment: Post any code that manipulate `vm.persons`. And inspect in browser that server return correct response. This will help if this server side or client side issue.

Comment: It's quite possibly to do with time-zones, if you check the time (along with any offset) that comes back with the date before and after the conversion, that might highlight the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using moment js or something to get UTC date. This is a common problem between server and UI